# Is 'hashing' more efficient than 'linear' search?

Tags: java, hash, collections

I decided to revise Java collection framework, so I started with internal implementation. One question came on my mind, which I can't solve. Hope someone can make a clear explanation on following.

ArrayList uses linear or binary search (both have pros/cons), but we can do anything with them! My question is why do all 'hashing' classes (like HashMap f.e.) use hashing principle? Couldn't they settle with linear or binary search for example? Why just not store Key/Value pair inside array? And the opposite, why isn't (for example ArrayList stored in hashTable)?

Answer (score 3):

The intention of the collections framework is that the programmer will choose the data structure appropriate to the use case.  Depending on what you're using it for, different data structures are appropriate.

Hashing classes use the hashing principle, as you put it, because if you choose them, then that's what you want to use.  (Hashing is generally the best choice for simple, straightforward lookups.)  A screwdriver uses the screwing principle because if you pick up a screwdriver, you want to screw something in; if you had a nail you needed to put in, you would have picked up the hammer instead.

But if you're not *going* to be performing lookups, or if linear search is good enough for you, then an `ArrayList` is what you want.  It's not *worth* adding a hash table to a collection that's never going to use it, and it costs CPU and memory to do things you aren't going to need.

Comment: Thank friend, I agree, but it didn't actually answer my question. I am still not getting how hashing is more efficient than linear or binary. Why add another overwhelm? Couldn't they fix K,V pair with those two already?

Comment: It's more efficient because it takes O(1) instead of O(log n) or O(n); it has to compare a constant number of keys to find the target on average.  It's faster, by a considerable margin, at the expense of moderate memory overhead.

Comment: Searching in a Linked List for example takes linear time (*O(n)*), as you would have to search through the entire list for your value. Searching in a Hash Table takes constant time (*O(1)*) as you get the index of the value directly from the value itself (`hash-function').

Comment: Then why don't all classes use hashing when it is that efficient? I get what you are saying, but I am still not 'clear in my head' :D And does ArrayList.get(5) actually goes linear 0,1,2.. or it can get (jump to) 5th index immidiately?

Comment: They don't use it because not everybody wants to pay the cost for the memory usage when they're not going to need it.  `ArrayList.get(5)` can jump to that index immediately.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You want to say that having more size in array takes more memory than having more nodes in hashtable? But getting 5th node(bucket) in hashtable is faster than getting 5th element in array? Am I getting closer?

Comment: Both of those comments are wrong, unfortunately.  Getting the 5th bucket in a hash table takes exactly the same amount of time as getting the 5th element in an array.  But finding the hash bucket associated with the string `"apple"` is faster than checking every element of an array for `"apple"`.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. But what if I have arrayList and I want to get that 'apple' and I don't know its index. I would have to do some additional work. Wouldn't in this case be better to implement hashtable in ArrayList? Still a little confused, sorry I am beginner :/

Comment: The intention is that if you have a collection, you want to find `"apple"`, and you don't know its index, then you would choose to use a hash-based collection instead of `ArrayList` in the first place.

Comment: @LouisWasserman that holds time complexity wise (O(n) is asymptotically bigger than O(1)) but if the premise for the answer is that we may have a fairly small map it's no longer so clear. Checking 5 strings for equality may very well be faster than constructing a hash of a single string (especially if it's a crypto-safe hash), and that delta only gets bigger for simple types line a 32 bit integer (can vectorize! is nice to branch predictor!)

Answer (score 1):

I had a large hash of values (about 1,500). The nature of the code was that once the hashmap was loaded it would never be altered. The hashmap was accessed many times per web page, and I had wondered if it could be sped up for faster page loading.

One day I had some time, so I did a series of time tests (using the nano time function). I then reworked the hashmap use over to an array. Not an ArrayList, but an actual array[]. I stored the index with the key class used to get the hash value.

There was a difference, that the array lookup was faster. I calculated that over a days worth of activity I would have saved almost a full second!

So yes, using an array is faster than using a hash, YMMV :-)

And I reverted my code back to using a hashmap, as it was easier to maintain...